# Function that can take two parameters and remove any object in the list that is of not of the type specified in second parameter?

Tags: python

Creating a function that takes two parameters. First paramteter should be a type list and the second parameter should be a type. Function should remove any object in the list that is of not of the specified in the second parameter.

```
input = ["5 ft", 2, 3.0, 8], float
output = [3.0]
```

Pretty lost on how to even start.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function:

```py
def remove_invalid_types(list1, type1):
    list2 = []

    for item in list1:
        if type(item) == type1:
            list2.append(item)

    return list2


print(remove_invalid_types(["5 ft", 2, 3.0, 8], float))
```